# What is the command to start chromium browser from the terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, application

How can I run applications from terminal?
For some applications I can find the path/name using `which` or `whatis`: `which python` or `whatis mathematica` or `whatis math`, but I can't run them by typing `mathematica` or `math`.
However, `python` works fine and I don't know what command I should give to `chromium` to run it. I can give a command to `tor-browser` to run in terminal, though.

I am using `Debian Stretch` with `Gnome` desktop.

Answer (score 8):

Try `chromium-browser`.

If that doesn't work, issue the command `dpkg-query -L chromium` to list all the files installed during installation of chromium browser. One of these files will be your binary.

Comment: chromium-browser worked for LinuxMint 18, dpkg-query -L chromium-browser worked, but  dpkg-query -L chromium returned nothing.

Comment: Note that `chromium-browser` is an Ubuntu-specific thing they do to distinguish the version shipped in form of a [Snap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(package_manager)) from the version that is distributed as a Debian package. You can actually install them both in parallel. On Debian stretch, which is used by the OP, [the name is just `chromium`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/chromium/filelist).

Answer (score 2):

To start the chromium web browser in ubuntu, try the following command :

```
chromium
```

Please note it is just *chromium* and not *chromium-browser*

Comment: [As of eoan](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=eoan&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=chromium), there is no `chromium` for the browser. It's still [`chromium-browser`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=any&keywords=chromium-browser&searchon=contents)

Comment: Note that the OP is using Debian stretch.

Answer (score 1):

Find the actual name of your application and then type it in the terminal:

```
chromium-browser
```

If you've run the application from GUI before, right-click the name in the menu and you should see the command/path of the application under Properties. That is where the actual name could be found as well.

Or you could search for it using `find` or `apt-cache search` or ...

Or maybe you have to add its location to `PATH`.

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/chromium
```

The world is full of options.

Comment: Thank you slybloty. I was looking for that, right click and command. I can find paths of many (almost all installed programs with it).However there occurs the problem when I try to do that with Mathematica in /bin/sh/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.2/Executables, right clicking does not show the dialogue box with "command" in it. The dialogue box which appears has no "command" line/section. However, I found a path where there is a Mathematica icon, when I right click on it, it shows the command which I can use to run it from terminal. Path was /usr/share.

Answer (score 1):

On Raspberry Pi Ubuntu I did this to start a webpage, fullscreen (in Kiosk mode):

```
# put in ~/.bash_profile
DISPLAY=:0 chromium-browser --app=https://your.website —kiosk &
```

Comment: will this work on any ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 0):

To start up a program, you need the package name (eg. python, chromium-browser, etc.), it's what you typed when you installed the program from terminal. To start it, just type the package name. If you don't know the name, google it, or use `dpkg -l | less`, and search the package names for to one you want using the arrow keys. Press q to exit.

Comment: Note that the name of the executable might differ from the package name.

Comment: @martin Noted. By the way, if that's so, just google the executable name.

Answer (score 0):

Note that on Unix systems you have a few options when it comes to calling executables:

1. You can type the full path. For example

   ```
   $ /usr/bin/nano
   ```
2. You can type a relative path. For example

   ```
   /usr/lib$ ../bin/nano
   ```

   There is a common pitfall for Unix newbies: If you want to call an executable from the current working directory you have to say

   ```
   /usr/bin$ ./nano
   ```

   Note that this is different from Windows where you don't need the `./` (on the up side these two additional characters can often prevents surprises).
3. You can just type `nano` in which case it will be searched in the directories specified by your `PATH` environment variable. This pattern should work for all programs installed as packages.

   If it doesn't work check your search path. Here's what I get as a regular user on my machine:

   ```
   $ echo $PATH
   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
   ```

   Note that the search path for privileged users (root) typically includes additional directories like `/usr/sbin` containing executables that usually aren't too useful for regular users.